# How to get four coordinates based on four end points

Tags: python, excel, math, graph

Let's say in a graph I have four endpoints of four corners as

```
C1(0,0) C2(0,9) C3(9,9) C4(9,0).
```

Is it possible to get four coordinates(distance from four endpoints), when a target is somewhere in middle of four endpoints.

Like if I place target at:

(7,1) with respect to C1 end point.

Added I should get as:
(2,1) from C4 & similarly from C2 & C3 as well.

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Did you try to start to code this script ? If yes, please share it, and ask where you have an issue.

Comment: No. Am stuck in initial stage how to frame this specification. Googling for any clues, meanwhile posted here to seek expertise clues as well.

Comment: Well this is easy math, isn't it. Assume the you got the points as list or as tulple (x, y). And your target is also a tuple of the same kind, then the vectors from endpoint to target are just the differences between each endpoint and the target. Meaning dist = (x_endpoint - x_target, y_endpoint - y_target).

Comment: As per Rennnyyy statement, then from C2- (7,8) & C3 ( 2,8). Right ??.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this:

```
C1 = (0,0)
C2 = (0,9)
C3 = (9,9)
C4 = (9,0)

T = (7,1)

T_C1 = (abs(T[0]-C1[0]),abs(T[1]-C1[1])) # Finding to difference between the x,y coordinates of T (target) and C1
T_C2 = (abs(T[0]-C2[0]),abs(T[1]-C2[1])) # Finding to difference between the x,y coordinates of T (target) and C2
T_C3 = (abs(T[0]-C3[0]),abs(T[1]-C3[1])) # Finding to difference between the x,y coordinates of T (target) and C3
T_C4 = (abs(T[0]-C4[0]),abs(T[1]-C4[1])) # Finding to difference between the x,y coordinates of T (target) and C4

print(T_C1,T_C2,T_C3,T_C4)
```

Output:

```
(7, 1) (7, -8) (-2, -8) (-2, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Rennnyyy. Yes it's very basic one. Wondering how did I miss it.

Comment: Is it possible to make it live ? Within excel or python. Let say can draw a graph with this four endpoints & move a target around & get the distance from each coordinator. If possible get it saved in excel ?

Comment: Yes, with the turtle module.